# How to send IEnumurable request to a web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to receive a request in WeB API, and the request class type is IEnumurable. I am testing it using postman but always it comes as null value. Below is my code piece:
When I removed IEnumurable from the request class, I am able to get the values from POSTMAN.

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("PostTotalLossData")]
public IHttpActionResult PostTotalLossData([FromBody]TotalLossReviewedStatusRequest reviewedStatusReq)
{
    try
    {
        if (reviewedStatusReq != null)
        {
            var result = _iTLTT_BAL.UpdateTotalLossReviewedStatus(reviewedStatusReq);
            //return Ok(result);
            return Ok(reviewedStatusReq);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Info("Invalid request received, Request : " + reviewedStatusReq);
            return Ok("Invalid request");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }           
}
```

Request Class:

```
namespace CTS.NextGen.API.TLTT.Models.Request
{
    [Serializable]
    public class TotalLossReviewedStatusRequest : IEnumerable<TotalLossReviewedStatus>
    {
        public List<TotalLossReviewedStatus> totalLossReviewedStatuses { get; set; }

        public IEnumerator<TotalLossReviewedStatus> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.totalLossReviewedStatuses.GetEnumerator();
            
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.totalLossReviewedStatuses.GetEnumerator();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Postman request body:

```
{
"totalLossReviewedStatuses" : [
    {
  "n_claimNumber" : "123456678",
   "n_damageID" : "123rtyui89",
   "b_initiialReviewed" : "12/09/2020",
   "b_reviewed" :"Y",
   "heloo":"N"
    },
    {
  "n_claimNumber" : "123456678",
   "n_damageID" : "123rtyui89",
   "b_initiialReviewed" : "12/09/2020",
   "b_reviewed" :"Y"
    }
 ]
    
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Instead of implementing IEnumerable, just declare your request as a `List<TotalLossReviewedStatus>` which already implements enumerable and will accept a JSON array.

Comment: If you are expecting `IEnumerable` then should your post body should be `array` type instead of `object.

Comment: The request takes IEnumerable of what type? You just pass a List<T> or T[] or any other collection that implements IEnumerable.

Comment: Not sure, but I'm thinking maybe you're having an issue because your `TotalLossReviewedStatusRequest` inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`, but the value being sent is neither an array nor array-like. As others have said above, having it inherit from `IEnumerable<T>` is pointless. Just remove the inheritance and use the `IEnumerable<T>` within it.

Answer (score 0):

Your request body should be `array` type instead of `object` type. Change the input request body as

```
[    
   {
    "totalLossReviewedStatuses" : [
        {
      "n_claimNumber" : "123456678",
       "n_damageID" : "123rtyui89",
       "b_initiialReviewed" : "12/09/2020",
       "b_reviewed" :"Y",
       "heloo":"N"
        },
        {
      "n_claimNumber" : "123456678",
       "n_damageID" : "123rtyui89",
       "b_initiialReviewed" : "12/09/2020",
       "b_reviewed" :"Y"
        }
     ]
        
    }
    {
       ..........Other objects. If not needed then remove this object declaration
    }
]
```